# PostgreSQL statement caching interfering with expected results

Tags: python, sql, postgresql

We've written a PL/pgSQL function to record timestamps to an audit table.
PostgresSQL statement caching however is not recalculating `now()` on each
invocation, which is causing stale (meaning old) timestamps to be recorded in our audit table.

We're running Postgres 9.2. According to the docs
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/plpgsql-implementation.html#PLPGSQL-PLAN-CACHING (scroll to bottom of their article), the recommendation is to rely on calls to `now()`.

This function does not work as expected:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION save(txd integer) RETURNS void AS $$
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO audit (id, mtime) VALUES (txd,now());
END;$$
```

With a table defined as:

```
CREATE TABLE audit (
  id integer NOT NULL,
  mtime timestamp without time zone NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT audit_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
  )
```

A simple python 2.7 script using `psycopg2` can be used to demonstrate the problem:

```
import datetime, psycopg2, time
def tm():
    # connect and clear contents
    con = psycopg2.connect('dbname=postgres user=postgres')
    cur = con.cursor()
    cur.execute('TRUNCATE audit')

    # Add a record, wait a second, add another
    cur.execute('SELECT save(1)')
    time.sleep(1.0)
    cur.execute('SELECT save(2)')

    # List the contents
    cur.execute('SELECT * FROM audit')
    for row in cur.fetchall():
        print("modified %s" % row[1])
    cur.close()
    con.close()
```

If you run this script, you will notice that the two instances of modified times will report the exact same value, even though we inserted a small 1-second sleep between INSERTs

```
>>> tm()
modified 2016-05-10 11:05:21.766005
modified 2016-05-10 11:05:21.766005
```

Note: We have even tried the example provided by postgres in the linked
article. There is no difference in output using their example:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION save(txd integer) RETURNS void AS $$
DECLARE
    curtime timestamp;
BEGIN
    curtime = 'now';
    INSERT INTO audit (id, mtime) VALUES (txd,curtime);
END;$$
```

Could someone set us straight on where we're going wrong here?

Comment: `now()` returns the timestamp **at transaction begin**. If you want the actual time at sub-trransaction level you'll need `clock_timestamp()` http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/functions-datetime.html

Comment: Thanks much! If you make this the answer, I will award.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`now()` returns the timestamp **at transaction begin**; this will cause all clock readings within the transaction to yield the same value (which is often what you want).

If you want the actual time at sub-transaction level, you'll need `clock_timestamp()` http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/functions-datetime.html